# how to fix (CSRF token missing or incorrect ) react/redux + django

Tags: reactjs, django, react-redux, csrf

i'm developing authentication

[login_page localhost:8000/login/][1]

i tried to login but my state is LOGIN_FAIL

[LOGIN_FAIL][2]

I've checked it's working on postman and I know my template should have this code.

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

But, If I paste this code into Login.js, it makes an error. Like this

Login.js:

```
const Login = ({ login }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email , password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    login(email, password);
  };

  // Is the user authenticated
  // Redirect them to the home page

  return (
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <div className="container mt-5"> 
        {/* <h1>회원가입</h1>
        <p>이메일로 회원가입</p> */}
        <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className="form-group">
            
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="email"
              placeholder="이메일"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="password"
              placeholder="비밀번호"
              name="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              minLength='6'
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button className='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>login</button>
        </form>
        <p className='mt-3'>
          <Link to='/signup'>signin</Link>
        </p>
        <p className='mt-3'>
        <Link to='/reset_password'>find password</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

error code:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /http//localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/
[04/Feb/2021 01:33:26] "POST /http//localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2513
```

authentication trigger code:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);

    dispatch ({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch (load_user());
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch ({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
    });
  }
};
```

MIDDLEWARE code :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Any hint would be appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVXfX.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mWSA.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use redux, you can use redux-csrf package.

```
npm install redux-csrf --save
```

Then you can use the setCsrfToken(token) API that set the CSRF token in the Redux store.

Please refer here. [enter link description here](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-react-forms-csrf-axios/)